# Adding numbers in an array, getting output NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Can't figure out why I'm getting NaN. Trying to write a function that accepts an array of numbers and returns the sum of all numbers in the array. Tried the same with forEach - worked perfectly.

```
function sumArray(numArr){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i <= numArr.length; i++){
      sum += numArr[i]   
    }
   return sum;
}
sumArray();
```

Comment: In the `for` loop, remove the `=` from `<=` - you are iterating the array one time too many...
A call `sumArray()` won't work because no array is passed...
Try `sumArray([1,2,3])` - will return `6`.

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using - Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Try using i<numArr.length instead of i<=numArr.length. The array index begins at 0 and ends at n-1, where n is the length of the array. You're trying to access an index outside the array bounds which would return undefined and adding a number to an undefined gives NaN.

Comment: The site doesn't let me vote but thank you so much, it worked